# Learning about Inheritance, and can't get my calculations to work

Tags: java, class, inheritance, math, subclass

The assignment asks the following to be performed, and i am having trouble getting anything but 0 to show for area or volume. I don't know if it is an inheritance problem, or a math problem (i think i casted to int properly?)
Any help would be appreciated.

> Design and then implement three different classes that work together to define shapes: Round Shape, Cone, and Sphere. For each class, store fundamental data about its size and provide methods to access and modify this data. In addition, provide appropriate methods to compute the area, and volume, for Sphere and Cone.
>
> In your design, consider how shapes are related and thus where inheritance can be implemented. Don't create duplicate instance variables. Create a main method which instantiates 2 Sphere objects (any parameters), 2 Cone objects (any parameters), display them with ToString(), change one parameter (your choice) in each, and display them again.
>
> Attached is an optional basefile that will help you define the different classes in the same file. Remember that you MUST rename the base file and class to contain your last name.

Here is my code. The assignment makes us submit it all in one file, vice separate files for each class, which is why they're all in the same file.

```
public class Coughlin_A04Q1
{
public int radius;
public int height;
public int area;
public int volume;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Cone cone1 = new Cone(10,20);
    Cone cone2 = new Cone(5,10);
    Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere(3);
    Sphere sphere2 = new Sphere(5);
    System.out.println(cone1);
    System.out.println(cone2);
    System.out.println(sphere1);
    System.out.println(sphere2);


}


public static class Round extends Coughlin_A04Q1
{

private int volume()
{
return (int)(Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2.0) * height);
}
private int area()
{
return (int)((2*Math.PI*radius*height) + (2*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2)));
}
public Round(int radius, int height)
{
this.radius = radius;
this.height = height;
}
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static class Cone extends Coughlin_A04Q1
{


public Cone(int radius, int height)
{
    this.radius = radius;
    this.height = height;
}
public int area()
{
return (int)(Math.PI*radius*(radius +      

Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height,2.0)+Math.pow(height,2.0))));
}
public int volume()
{
return (int)(Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2)*(height/3));
}
public String toString()
{
    return "A Cone of radius: " +radius+ ", area: "+area+", and volume: "  

+volume+".";
}
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static class Sphere extends Coughlin_A04Q1
{

public Sphere(int radius)
{
    this.radius=radius;
}
public int area()
{
return (int)(4*Math.PI*Math.pow(this.radius,2));

}

public int volume()
{
return (int)((4/3)*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,3));

}
public String toString()
{
    return "A Sphere of radius: " +radius+ ", area: "+ area +", and volume: 

" +volume+".";
}
}
}
```

Comment: You show a lot of code, but no results.  Show the results and any error messages.

Comment: Sorry, here is the output.  A Cone of radius: 10, area: 0, and volume: 0.  A Cone of radius: 5, area: 0, and volume: 0.  A Sphere of radius: 3, area: 0, and volume: 0.  A Sphere of radius: 5, area: 0, and volume: 0.

Comment: `int` refers to integers. Why not using `double` or `float` to compute areas and volumes ? Beware that `4/3` is `1`...

Comment: The biggest problem is that the function `ToString` return the values of the members `area` and `volume` of class `Coughlin_A04Q1`, which are never modified, even in functions `area()` and `volume()`.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an interface:

```
package math.Shapes;

/**
 * 3DShape interface
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 2/7/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258063/learning-about-inheritance-and-cant-get-my-calculations-to-work
 */
public interface Shape3D {
    double area();
    double volume();
}
```

Implement Cone:

```
package math.Shapes;

/**
 * Cone 3D shape
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 2/7/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258063/learning-about-inheritance-and-cant-get-my-calculations-to-work
 */
public class Cone implements Shape3D {

    private final double radius;
    private final double height;

    public Cone(double radius, double height) {
        if (radius <= 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("radius must be positive");
        if (height <= 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("height must be positive");
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return Math.PI*this.radius*(this.radius+this.getDiscriminant());
    }

    @Override
    public double volume() {
        return Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius*this.height/3.0;
    }

    private double getDiscriminant() {
        double discriminant = 0.0;
        if (this.radius > this.height) {
            double ratio = this.height/this.radius;
            discriminant = this.radius*Math.sqrt(1.0+ratio*ratio);
        } else {
            double ratio = this.radius/this.height;
            discriminant = this.height*Math.sqrt(1.0+ratio*ratio);
        }
        return discriminant;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("radius: %10.3f height: %10.3f area: %10.3f volume: %10.3f", this.radius, this.height, this.area(), this.volume());
    }
}
```

Implement Sphere:

```
package math.Shapes;

/**
 * Sphere class
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 2/7/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258063/learning-about-inheritance-and-cant-get-my-calculations-to-work
 */
public class Sphere implements Shape3D {

    private final double radius;

    public Sphere(double radius) {
        if (radius <= 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("radius must be positive");
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return 4.0*Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double volume() {
        return this.area()*this.radius/3.0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("radius: %10.3f area: %10.3f volume: %10.3f", this.radius, this.area(), this.volume());
    }
}
```

Finally the driver to test it all:

```
package math.Shapes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Driver for Shape3D
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 2/7/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258063/learning-about-inheritance-and-cant-get-my-calculations-to-work
 */
public class DriverShape3D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Shape3D> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape3D>() {{
            add(new Cone(1.0, 1.0));
            add(new Sphere(1.0));
            add(new Cone(5.0, 5.0));
            add(new Sphere(5.0));
        }};
        for (Shape3D shape : shapes) {
            System.out.println(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep it simple.  Pay attention to style and format: Readability is everything.